# Error on django-bootstrap-icons for cusom_icon in django project

Tags: python, django

Normal bootstrap icon is working fine. like *{% bs_icon 'slack' size='2em' %}*.

But when I am going to use **custom_icon** using **django_bootstrap_icons** module by using *{% custom_icon 'c-program' %}*. Its producing error:

```
KeyError at /
'fill-rule'

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 4.1.8
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'fill-rule'
Exception Location: /opt/setup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/html.py, line 103, in format_html
Raised during:  apps.bio.views.IndexView
Python Executable:  /opt/setup/.venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.16
Python Path:    
['/workdir/src',
 '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/opt/setup/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

Comment: have you run your custom svg through a validator to make sure it's well formed?  It looks like the svg data is bubbling up through the module then failing when it gets to format_html, possibly because your SVG file has something like `fill-rule` rather than `fill-rule=""`

Comment: Thanks a lot @SamSparx, I have validated and seemed my SVG file has problem to render because of fill-rule. Kudos